# Inequality with absolute value and variable on both sides

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I'm not able to understand how to get through this

$$\dfrac{|x+6|}{x+1} \leq x-2$$

$x$ can't, of course, be equal to $-1$.

I'm at a point where I'm not sure how to deal with the absolute value after reaching

$$|x+6| \leq (x-2)(x+1)$$

Thanks!

Comment: $|x+6| = \sqrt{(x+6)^2}$

Comment: Remember to note that in multiplying across by $(x+1)$ and keeping the inequality sign the same implies $x>-1$.

Comment: John Doe thanks that's one thing that was missing in my answer which I didn't pay attention to..can you link me to somewhere with an explanation to that ?

Comment: Is it possible for the absolute value to replace it once with positive and once as negative and then deal with it as a normal inequality ?

Comment: One approach would be to solve separately (a) $-(x+6) \geq (x+1)(x-2)$ and $x \lt -6$, (b) $(x+6) \geq (x+1)(x-2)$ and $-6 \le x \lt -1$ and (c) $(x+6) \leq (x+1)(x-2)$ and $-1 \le x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at this case by case.

**Case 1:** $x\leq-6$

Then you had $x+1\leq-5$, and so when multiplying across, the inequality sign changes. Also, $|x+6|=6-x$, so: $$6-x\geq(x-2)(x+1)=x^2-x-2\implies x^2\leq8$$ This is not possible since $x\leq -6$.

**Case 2:** $-6\leq x<-1$

Then you still had $x+1<0$, but now $|x+6|=x+6$, so
$$x+6\geq x^2-x-2\implies x^2-2x-8\leq0\implies-2\leq x\leq 4$$
From this range, only $-2\leq x<-1$ works.

**Case 3:** $x>-1$

Then $$x+6\leq x^2-x-2\implies x^2-2x-8\geq0\implies x\leq-2\text{ or }x\geq4$$
From this range, only $x\geq4$ works.

---

Final solution: $x\in[-2,-1)$ or $x\in[4,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{|x+6|}{x+1} \leq x-2$$

Let's start with $\dfrac{|x+6|}{x+1} = x-2$.

\begin{array}{rclcrcl}
     |x+6|  &= &(x+1)(x-2)  &| \\
   x^2-x-2  &= &|x+6|       &|\\
   x^2-x-2  &= &x+6         &\text{or}  & x^2-x-2 &= &-x-6 \\
   x^2-2x-8 &= &0           &\text{or}  & x^2+4 &= &0 \\
          x &\in &\{-2,4\}  &\text{or}  &     x &\in &\emptyset \\
\end{array}

So we have three critical points: zeros at $x=-2$ and $x=4$ and a pole at $x=-1$. The critical points divide the real number line into four regions:
$(-\infty, -2), (-2,-1), (-1, 4)$, and $(4, \infty).$ Each region is either all solutions or all no solutions. We test each region.

\begin{array}{c}
   \text{region} & \text{sample point} & \text{Is solution?} \\
\hline
   (-\infty, -2) & -10  & \text{no} \\
   (-2,-1)       & -1.5 & \text{yes} \\
   (-1, 4)       &    0 & \text{no}\\
   (4, \infty)   &   12 & \text{yes} \\
\hline
\end{array}

So the solution set is $[-2,-1) \cup [4, \infty)$.